# Should pre-Islamic questions like "Did women in Arabian peninsula have “Hijab” before Islam?" (7830) be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic-definition

Should questions on pre-Islamic history (like, [Did women in Arabian peninsula have "Hijab" before Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7830)) be on-topic, unless their relevance is established *by* OP?

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, there's two classes of "pre-Islamic history" that need to be recognized here:

### Contemporary *jahiliyya*

This would refer to those customs and traditions that were practiced and/or commonly known and accepted during the time of the prophet.  As he did not preach to a vacuum, the value of understanding the non-Islamic culture that he was actually preaching *to* cannot be dismissed, especially when dealing with jurisprudent methodologies that emphasise *[urf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urf)*.

The example question in OP is (or probably should be) an example of this, as there would appear to be value in recognizing whether the practice of "hijab" is actually *revelation* versus it being a pre-Islamic custom that was simply condoned or co-opted.

### Historical *jahiliyya*

Culture and history that was only relevant to generations *before* the the prophet is a different story altogether.  This is not to say that such situations are never relevant to Islam or Islamic studies: In many cases, an historical event can still fall into the contemporary category because it was commonly known and accepted (e.g. the story of Ashaab-il Fil) or it can have clear Islamic relevance by being directly referenced in the Islamic literature (again e.g. the story of Ashaab-il Fil).

However, if the connection to Islamic study is not obvious, significantly more effort would need to be expended on the questioner's part to demonstrate on-topicness.  Otherwise, such questions would almost inevitably be better suited to [History.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com).